# I have got my HelloListView app working from android.com what is the best way to add information

Tags: java, android, new-operator

I wanted to make an app that you can select a country and it comes up with information about the country. I don't know that much about Java i'm hoping that this will help me learn more about java.
I would like this to be an android app
please help me
thanks
CS

edit: I am new to java so can you help me out and give me pointers on how to do this please.

Example: Lets say we have a listview that has the United States, Germany, and the UK
I already have the list view set up. How would i go about making a second view that would let me select the us and give basic information about it?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: i edited the question it is above

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I am still a little unclear as to what you are asking but as far as I am aware the list view you create should be able handle clicks on it, so if you check out the ListView class in the android SDK there you will need to look for the onClick event you are after. Overload it and put in the code to create (I think you are asking for this) a second activity, to then show your selection. However that might be a bit complex so try and handle the click event first by perhaps a toast message. Then work your way up.

The second activity you could use to show information, or just create a dialog, or another full screen view to show the info.

Comment: would it help if i posted the code for the HelloGridView project?

Comment: the project does handle click events

Comment: im new to java so can you tell me how to do it? please

Answer (score 0):

I commend you for getting ListView to work without knowing Java.  I would suggest you learn the language first before jumping into Android apps because the development resources assume that you have a good knowledge of the Java.  There are lots of resources on the web for learning Java and you can do it all in the Eclipse environment if you wish.

Good luck!